# How to solve this AB test question?

Tags: confidence-interval, ab-test

Assume you were tasked with improving the listing conversion rate on xx.com. You build an A/B test with 2 variants.

- Control: Listings page has a button that reads “Reserve a Room”
- Test: Listings page has a button that reads “Book Now”

You find the average conversion rate for your control variant as 20% and the average conversion of the test variant as 22% with a confidence interval as (19.2,24.5). This is with a statical significance of level 95% and power of 80%.

Would you consider the test successful and go with the test variant? If not, why?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What progress have you made with your homework problem?

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this. I thought I understood the concept this question is making my mind crazy

Comment: What does the confidence interval tell you?

Comment: the confidence interval tells that the conversion rate should lie between 19.2 and 24.5 95% times

Comment: So what does that tell you about $20\%?$

Comment: I think it means that 20% falls in this interval and also the same is 22% bucket

Comment: @Dave Some caution is warranted here because 20% is just an estimate and likely has the same amount of uncertainty as the test proportion.  It is unclear what has "statistical significance of 95%"is intended to mean: a valid comparison of these two proportions (two-sample Binomial test perhaps?), a comparison of the test proportion to 20% (which would be invalid), or something else?  Indeed, why is any statement about power being made at all? Also, what would constitute a "successful test"?  This question leaves much to be desired pedagogically!

Comment: Yet another illustration that it is important to have _numerical counts_ of successes and numbers of subjects--rather than _percentages._ With some detective work you might be able to approximate the number of Test subjects, but without knowing the number of Control subjects you have no idea how much information there is about Control subjects. If "20%" arose from one Success in only five Control subjects, then the fact that $0.2$ happens to lie in the CI for Test subjects doesn't tell you much.

Answer (score 1):

With some trial and error one might guess that the number of Test subjects
was *roughly* $n_T= 900.$ That sample size would have given an exact 95% binomial confidence
interval $(19.3, 24.9)$ percent, an approximate 95% normal confidence
interval of $(19.4, 24.9)$ percent (from `prop.test`), a Wald CI of $(19.3, 24.7)$ percent, or a Jeffreys interval $(10.4, 24.8)$ percent.

```
n = 900; binom.test(.22*n, n)$conf.int
[1] 0.1933333 0.2485131
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

n=900;  prop.test(.22*n, n)$conf.int
[1] 0.1936290 0.2487998
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

.22 + qnorm(c(.025, .975))*(sqrt(.22*.78/900))
[1] 0.1929364 0.2470636  # Wald 95% CI

qbeta(c(.025,.975), 198+.5, 900-198+.5)
[1] 0.1938626 0.2479349  $ Jeffreys
```

Furthermore, if we **assume that there were also about $n_C=900$ Control subjects,** then
`prop.test` in R does not find a significant difference between
proportions $0.20$ and $0.22.$

```
prop.test(round(c(900*.20, 900*.22)), c(900,900), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  round(c(900 * 0.2, 900 * 0.22)) out of c(900, 900)
X-squared = 1.085, df = 1, p-value = 0.2976
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.05762133  0.01762133
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.20   0.22
```

*Note:* With $2200$ subjects in each group, `prop.test` shows a
significant difference in proportions at the 4% level. The Jeffreys interval for Control does not contain 22% and the Jeffreys interval for Treatment does not contain 20%. However, the two
Jeffreys intervals are not disjoint.

```
prop.test(round(c(2200*.20, 2200*.22)), c(900,900), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.03799416

2200*.20; 2200*.22
[1] 440
[1] 484
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 440+.5, 2200-440+.5)
[1] 0.1836862 0.2171026
qbeta(c(.025,.975), 484+.5, 2200-484+.5)
[1] 0.2030653 0.2376708
```